# Unable to sign in with redirect with firebase on mobile

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my application I am trying to sign in with google redirect. My redirect login works on my chrome browser but my safari browser does not work.

Here is some code that I have that works on chrome

```js
  try {
      const result = await getRedirectResult(auth);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.code === 'auth/credential-already-in-use') {
        const cred = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(err);
        signInWithCredential(auth, cred);
      }
    }
```

In the above snippet, I see that `result` would contain the auth credential object. In safari, the auth credential is `null`. I've checked the documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices#signinwithpopup but I'm working with localhost and it's failing.

I found in this documenation https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#getredirectresult that `If no redirect operation was called, returns null.` So in this case, my guess is that the redirect operation was not called on my browser. What gives?